# Scrapear una lista sin etiqueta de wikipedia con BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_de_julio'
pagina_nac = requests.get(url, headers=header)
nacimientos_ = BeautifulSoup(pagina_nac.text, 'html.parser')
```

> No puedo acceder al contenedor de los elementos

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Nacimientos">Nacimientos</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=10_de_julio&amp;action=edit&amp;section=2" title="Editar sección: Nacimientos">editar</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/1419" title="1419">1419</a>: <a href="/wiki/Go-Hanazono_Tenn%C5%8D" title="Go-Hanazono Tennō">Go-Hanazono</a>, emperador japonés (f. 1471).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1451" title="1451">1451</a>: <a href="/wiki/Jacobo_III_de_Escocia" title="Jacobo III de Escocia">Jacobo III</a>, rey escocés (f. 1488).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1509" title="1509">1509</a>: <a href="/wiki/Juan_Calvino" title="Juan Calvino">Juan Calvino</a>, reformista religioso y filósofo francés (f. 1564).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1517" title="1517">1517</a>: <a href="/wiki/Odet_de_Coligny" title="Odet de Coligny">Odet de Coligny</a>, religioso francés, cardenal de Châtillon, convertido al protestantismo (f. 1571).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1561" title="1561">1561</a>: <a href="/wiki/Juan_Bautista_de_la_Concepci%C3%B3n" title="Juan Bautista de la Concepción">Juan Bautista de la Concepción</a>, religioso, místico y reformador de la Orden de la Santísima Trinidad (f. 1613).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1638" title="1638">1638</a>: <a href="/wiki/David_Teniers_III" title="David Teniers III">David Teniers III</a>, pintor flamenco (f. 1685).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1682" title="1682">1682</a>: <a href="/wiki/Roger_Cotes" title="Roger Cotes">Roger Cotes</a>, matemático británico (f. 1716).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1723" title="1723">1723</a>: <a href="/wiki/William_Blackstone" title="William Blackstone">William Blackstone</a>, jurista británico (f. 1780).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1724" title="1724">1724</a>: <a href="/wiki/Eva_Ekeblad" title="Eva Ekeblad">Eva Ekeblad</a>, científica sueca (f. 1786)</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1792" title="1792">1792</a>: <a href="/wiki/George_Mifflin_Dallas" title="George Mifflin Dallas">George Mifflin Dallas</a>, vicepresidente estadounidense (f. 1864).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1796" title="1796">1796</a>: <a href="/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Josefa_Garc%C3%ADa_Granados" title="María Josefa García Granados">María Josefa García Granados</a>, escritora guatemalteca (f. 1848).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1817" title="1817">1817</a>: <a href="/wiki/Miguel_Lafuente_Alc%C3%A1ntara" title="Miguel Lafuente Alcántara">Miguel Lafuente Alcántara</a>, escritor y arabista español (f. 1850).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1830" title="1830">1830</a>: <a href="/wiki/Camille_Pissarro" title="Camille Pissarro">Camille Pissarro</a>, pintor y anarquista francés (f. 1903).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1832" title="1832">1832</a>: <a href="/wiki/Alvan_Graham_Clark" title="Alvan Graham Clark">Alvan Graham Clark</a>, astrónomo estadounidense (f. 1897).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1834" title="1834">1834</a>: <a href="/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa_Sbarbi_y_Osuna" title="José María Sbarbi y Osuna">José María Sbarbi y Osuna</a>, religioso, filólogo y musicólogo español (f. 1910).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1835" title="1835">1835</a>: <a href="/wiki/Henryk_Wieniawski" title="Henryk Wieniawski">Henryk Wieniawski</a>, compositor polaco (f. 1880).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1851" title="1851">1851</a>: <a href="/wiki/Friedrich_von_Wieser" title="Friedrich von Wieser">Friedrich von Wieser</a>, economista austríaco (f. 1926).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1856" title="1856">1856</a>: <a href="/wiki/Otto_Krause" title="Otto Krause">Otto Krause</a>, ingeniero y educador argentino (f. 1920).</li>
<li>1856: <a href="/wiki/Nikola_Tesla" title="Nikola Tesla">Nikola Tesla</a>, ingeniero e inventor croata (f. 1943).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1867" title="1867">1867</a>: <a href="/wiki/Maximiliano_de_Baden" title="Maximiliano de Baden">Maximiliano de Baden</a>, aristócrata y canciller alemán (f. 1929).</li>
<li>1867: <a href="/wiki/Finley_Peter_Dunne" title="Finley Peter Dunne">Finley Peter Dunne</a>, humorista y periodista estadounidense (f. 1936).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1871" title="1871">1871</a>: <a href="/wiki/Marcel_Proust" title="Marcel Proust">Marcel Proust</a>, escritor francés (f. 1922).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1874" title="1874">1874</a>: <a href="/wiki/Sergu%C3%A9i_Koni%C3%B3nkov" title="Serguéi Koniónkov">Serguéi Koniónkov</a>, pintor ruso (f. 1971).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1875" title="1875">1875</a>: <a href="/wiki/Mary_McLeod_Bethune" title="Mary McLeod Bethune">Mary McLeod Bethune</a>, educador estadounidense (f. 1955).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1878" title="1878">1878</a>: <a href="/wiki/Otto_Freundlich" title="Otto Freundlich">Otto Freundlich</a>, escultor alemán (f. 1943).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1879" title="1879">1879</a>: <a href="/wiki/Heriberto_Jara" title="Heriberto Jara">Heriberto Jara</a>, militar y político mexicano (f. 1968).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1883" title="1883">1883</a>:
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/Johannes_Blaskowitz" title="Johannes Blaskowitz">Johannes Blaskowitz</a>, general alemán (f. 1948).</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Sam_Wood" title="Sam Wood">Sam Wood</a>, cineasta estadounidense (f. 1949).</li></ul></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/1888" title="1888">1888</a>: <a href="/wiki/Giorgio_de_Chirico" title="Giorgio de Chirico">Giorgio de Chirico</a>, pintor italiano (f. 1978).</li>
```

Estoy desesperado, Necesito solo quedarme con las fechas, pero no encuentro etiqueta del contenedor de el UL, para poder acceder a los LI, y dentro tambien hay Ul y otras LI

Perdon no se como preguntarlo o que compartir.
muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado utilizar

Comment: Prueba: nacimientos_ = BeautifulSoup(pagina_nac.text, 'lxml') li_data = soup.find("li")

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda solucionar el problema hace falta que tenga una explicación. También hay que tener en cuenta que no todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas si no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. A la pregunta le hace falta mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer.

Comment: _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ Recuerda además que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código: evita las respuestas en donde "se regala" código, y sin explicación. Lee [answer].